# Excel Macro for copying specific rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge spreadsheet of about 300001 rows and 20 columns. The first column A is a repetition of numbers from 0 to 3 in steps of 0.001 (3001 cells, 100 repetitions in total). I would like to pick out ROWS corresponding to the column A entry of 3, transpose them and write them to a new sheet. How do I do this? Total noob at macros and VBA but I am familiar with programming (mostly C++).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need macros to do something like this - but then again this seems more like something you are doing for fun than for anything practical.

You could just sort your range "A1:T300001" by column A from high to low and copy and paste the top hundred rows.

But if you want a macro that does this, this should work for you:

```
Sub MacroAutofilterExample()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$T$300001").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="3.000"

    Range("A1:T300001").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(2).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Obviously their are some efficiency losses by using selections(since I recorded parts of it) but you can change those to use set ranges - generally this should give you an idea.

**EDIT:**

You would change the field:

```
Transpose:=False
```

In the above code to:

```
Transpose:=True
```

If you wanted your results transposed.

Comment: Does auto-filering automatically sort entire rows/ I mean if I have two rows (2.99,5,6) and (3.00,1,2) will I see the second set of numbers moved up entirely or will I see columns get sorted as (3.00,5,6) and (2.99,1,2). I want to preserve the order of the set of numbers.

Comment: Autofiltering is different from sort. All it does is filter, it doesn't reorganize(in fact all it does is hide rows that don't meet your criteria). So the command Selection.AutoFilter in the above code returns your data to normal(to its initial state - it unhides all those previously hidden rows). So your initial ordering will not be lost. But in any case, if your initial ordering is important I would recommend you have a column that goes from 1 to 300001 - so you can sort on it and manipulate it freely without have to worry about losing any kind of ordering that is important to you.